# WinForms Metro UI

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using MetroFramework (https://github.com/dennismagno/winforms-modernui) in a GUI I'm developing at the moment, because it gives you a clean and better looking Controls than the Default ones.

I wantto use the TabControl specifically from this MetroFramework, however, I need tho change the Image displayed in each Tab itself, which I can if I'm using the Default Tabs, but I can't if I'm using this MetroFramework, because nothing happens even if using the same methods than before.

Does anyone used this MetroFramework and/or know how to change this behaviour?

I guess I could do this overriding the Paint method or something, but since I'm new to Winforms i really dont know how to do this...

DefaultTabs:

[image]

MetroFrameworkTabs:

[image]

Comment: Playing directly inside DrawTab() i was able to do what I intended. However, trying to implement an event handler to override the CustomPaintForeground I was not able to do it, since my event is never called? Could you tell me how to get me event triggered? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I have done it! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: I guess I have done it wrong. Since I started adding more Controls to the tabs, it was getting slower to redraw. Using a counter, I could see that the problem is this Event is being triggered +100 times , and even when I move the mouse with the pointer in the Form, it fires new events, causing the Tab to draw itself too many times... Do you have an idea why this is happening?